# Add summary statistics into facet_wrap labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

The following code makes a ggplot image with 4 facets:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

d <- msleep %>% 
    mutate(conservation_fct = fct_lump_n(conservation, 2))

ggplot(d, aes(x = sleep_total, y = awake)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ conservation_fct)
```

[image]

I want to add the group sample size for each of the levels of the facet `conservation_fct` to the facet labels. For example, I want the column `facet_titles` in the table below to become the labels for my facets.

```
d %>% 
  count(conservation_fct) %>%
  mutate(facet_titles = paste0(conservation_fct, " (n=", n , ")"))
```

I have attempted to extract that column using `pull()` and then feeding that into the `labeller` function but am not having any luck.

The four labels should read:

- `domesticated (n=10)`
- `lc (n=27)`
- `Other (n=17)`
- `NA (n=29)`

Has anyone got any pointers here? I know I could manually change the values using a case_when statement, but the longer-term aim is to pack this into a function and I want it to be flexible rather than hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_count()` seems like a better match than `count()` here, since we want to count how many observations are in each category and add that in a new column, but we don't want to collapse the observations into one row per category.

```
d <- msleep %>% 
  mutate(conservation_fct = fct_lump_n(conservation, 2)) %>%
  add_count(conservation_fct) %>%
  mutate(conservation_fct = as_factor(paste0(conservation_fct, " (n=", n , ")")))
```

[image]